# Vue Jasmine: Two different ways of triggering click result in different results

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, jasmine

I am having an issue when trying to switch the way I trigger clicks in my jasmine tests.  This is my current setup:

**Parent**

```
  <li ref="currentMovie">
    <MovieData :movie="currentMovieData" :isSubscribed="isSubscribed" @selected="handleMovie(currentMovieData)" />
  </li>
```

**Child (MovieData.vue)**

```
<template>
  <component :is="unType" v-bind="linkProps" :class="$style.container" data-ut="Movie-link" ref="link">
    <div data-ut="Movie-content" @click="showData ? $emit('selected') : false">
    </div>
  </component>
</template>
```

When creating my tests in the Parent component, I have:

(first method of triggering a click)

```
const movie = this.wrapper.vm.$refs.currentMovie;
triggerEvent(movie.querySelector('div'), 'click');
expect(this.wrapper.emitted().selected).toBeTruthy();
```

this works as expected and passes.  I am trying to switch to using from using `triggerEvent` to `data-ut` and doing this instead:

(second method of trigger a click)

```
this.wrapper.find(testID('Movie-content')).trigger('click');
expect(this.wrapper.emitted().selected).toBeTruthy();
```

I get:  `ERROR Some of your tests did a full page reload!`

Comment: It's not evident that the element is the same. The result suggests that it's not. `movie.querySelector('div')` - this results in flaky test because you didn't even check what an element is. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem

Comment: thank you.  Isn't it evident based on the fact that they are both targeting the same element?

Comment: The question doesn't contain the evidence they are targeting the same element, that's the point. That you have this problem suggests that that this conclusion is wrong, and you didn't check that it's the same in the test. The element you refer to is wrapped with  `<component` and it's unknown what happens there. I'd expect to see another div. Please, provide MCVE.